# Why one of my finger bones refuses to follow IK constraint

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, constraints

I recently added a question about how to make my finger bones follow a rotating crank handle.

That was solved.

But of course this was not a full solution as I now have a problem that has no logical explanation.

*** THE QUESTION ***

The four of my fingers are IK constraint to an empty object which is child of a rotating crank handle object.

It works absolutely without a problem, they follow the empty just as I wanted to. I placed the empty where I needed it to be placed and everything is fine.

However the thumb is not following the empty, even though it is IK to the empty the same way all other fingers are. Whenever I move the empty the thumb is also moving, but when I animate the empty, the thumb doesn't move, all other fingers are moving.

I was playing a lot and found out that if I was to unparent the eyes from the armature it fixes the problem somehow ? Makes absolutely no sense, I now need to have my character with no eyes in order to make my thumb follow the empty with IK constraint ? What is going wrong here and how to fully fix this ? Is it because I have too many parented objects or too many IK constraints ? If anyone have some sort of solution to this puzzle let me know. Thanks

[image: Eyes parented to armature]

[image: Unparenting the eyes]

File [here](https://filemail.com/d/nvgplpsbthlvhif)

Comment: hello, maybe share your file (remove the parts that are not useful)?

Comment: https://www.filemail.com/d/nvgplpsbthlvhif - Frame 711 is where it starts, I added child of constraint to the eyeballs with 0 influence but it still doesn't work, you need to fully remove the child of constraint in order for the thumb to start following the empty IK constraint. If I was to parent the eyes with ctrl+p same thing happens, I need to unparent before thumb starts moving again.

Comment: What a nightmare...

Comment: Well that is now creating a whole new world of problems because my weight painting skills r garbage and if I was to automatically paint weight the new bones for some reason the whole mesh is getting completely deformed

Comment: What a great way to fix things in Blender... Just redo it !  xD It does fix it for whatever messed up reason, I just need to fix the weight paint and re-animate the bones. Yikes. At least a solution. Thanks !

Comment: If I do that it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you have any idea why would unparenting the eyes fix the problem ?

Comment: I've found a way to make it work: Keep the bone but: Remove the Child Of of Empty1 and parent Empty1 to Empty, it seems to work

Comment: voalá ! That's it !! That fixed it for good !!!!! What an obvious solution, right ??? Thanks for helping me out ! I really appreciate it

Comment: well I'm unable to tell you why it didn't work with the Child Of (and also it looks like there are other problems as it doesn't work correctly with the previous versions of Blender)  ^^

Comment: Lets just hope I won't have any more of these problems as this project is not yet completed and I'm yet to create clothes in MD and simulate them and all that... But phew at least I can now move on... Thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a bug but I've found a way to make your animation work: Select *Empty1* and remove its *Child Of* constraint, parent *Empty1* to *Empty*.